# Delegate method not called from TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is the first time I'm working with `delegate` in swift. I've a table view with fixed three number of rows and every row has a seprate `.xib` for cell.

I'm adjusting the height of each cell based on the data I am getting in the cell. So as the `tableView` is loaded before and the cells are loaded after so I've defined a `protocol` in `UITableViewCell` class.

Above `CalenderTimeTableViewCell` class I've:

```
protocol ReloadingTable {
    func updateTableView()
}
```

Inside this class above `awakeFromNib()` I've: `var myDelegate: ReloadingTable?` and in the method I'm getting data (using Alamofire) I'm calling `self.myDelegate?.updateTableView()`.

In the `viewController` in which I've the `tableView` first of all I extended the class `ReloadingTable` and in this class I've:

```
func updateTableView() {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

By applying break points the code did get to the `self.myDelegate?.updateTableView()` but in `viewController` `updateTableView` method is not being called.

Comment: Where do you assign the target class to `myDelegate`?

Comment: You need to set the delegate as your ViewController. If you check value of self.myDelegate at your debug point, you will find it nil.

Comment: follow this link   http://stephenradford.me/creating-a-delegate-in-swift/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @vadian has commented you should assign target class to myDelegate

in cellForRowAt function assign target class to my delegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! CalenderTimeTableViewCell
    cell.myDelegate = self
    //Other
  }
```